# How do I properly setup pipenv in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I need krakenex in a project, so I import it with

```
import krakenex
```

I have one version of krakenex in

> /Users/x/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages

. When I execute the script and

```
print(krakenex)
```

it shows me the path mentioned above.

In the future, I want to use the modules from the packages I installed with e.g.

```
pipenv install krakenex
```

with priority.

How do I manage to do that? Is it sufficient to add the path of the virtual environment to the sys path, or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Consider marking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51566692/865175) as the solution.

Comment: Not the case anymore, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306431/pycharm-warns-package-requirement-not-satisfied-when-using-pipenv-to-install-pac

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should be pointing your Project Interpreter to the virtualenv python bin. So in PyCharm File->Settings->Project: ProjectName->Project Interpreter, then a windows showing the Project Interpreter should be displayed.

[image: Project Interpreter]

Next to the top dropdown is a gear and your going to want to Add Local and navigate to the virtualenvs python bin. Something like `virtualenvs/virtualenv_name/bin/python`. Then your project should be pointing to the right place.

Comment: This works great! Is there also a way to point pycharm to pipenv or pip so that one can install new modules via the pycharm fix action?

Comment: @Vibin PyCharm would use the `pip` that is linked to the project interpreter. The answer above should work for you installing things from within PyCharm.

Comment: @AlmogCohen unfortunately PyCharm doesn't use pipenv for installing new modules, even if the project interpreter is linked to pipenv environment.

Comment: Did this, and all my Run configurations no longer work :/ 
Had to edit the interpreter in each config to point to the virtualenv

Comment: @RamazanPolat PyCharm should add internal support for `pipenv`

Comment: @AlmogCohen They are adding it in the next release or if you felt like using an early access version it has it now. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/PyCharm+182.3341.8+Release+Notes

Comment: @ForFunAndProfit you are awesome. They are awesome!

Comment: @ForFunAndProfit please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306431/pycharm-warns-package-requirement-not-satisfied-when-using-pipenv-to-install-pac

Comment: This didn't work for me in the 2017 edition. Upgrading to 2019 resolved it.

Comment: On MacOS, go to PyCharm --> preferences --> Project: [project name] instead of file --> settings --> project

Answer (score 44):

To add more clarification on how to setup PyCharm with pipenv for now:

1. Execute in your project directory

   pipenv --venv

Save the output, you'll reference this path later

2. In PyCharm, Open Project Settings, and then select project interpreter
   [image: Preferences > Project Interpreter]
3. Click Add a Python Interpreter > System Interpreter > Select Python Interpreter and paste the output from the first command, appending /bin/python onto the end.
   [image]

Note that you will need to use the command line to install any packages since PyCharm currently doesn't support pipenv in their package management tools. However, I haven't had a problem with this method.

Answer (score 25):

PyCharm natively supports pipenv since version [`2018.2`](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/). PyCharm 2018.2 will automatically create a pipenv when you open a project with a Pipfile, and makes it easy to create new projects with pipenvs.

**For existing projects**

As previously stated, for existing projects with a `Pipfile`, when you open a Python file, PyCharm will ask you if you want to install the dependencies from the `Pipfile.lock`.

[image: pipenv for existing projects]

**For new projects**

For a new project, you can use the project interpreter panel to create a `Pipenv` based project interpreter.

[image]

Comment: The support for pipenv in pycharm is ridiculous as of 2018.3. PyCharm doesn't even check if there already is an existing virtualenv, it just creates a new one (it should check with pipenv --venv). Furthermore pipenv respects the WORKON_HOME env variable, which cannot be set in PyCharm.

Comment: @Toby, I think now it checks. I am using 2018.3.1, and it is actually looking for the virtual environment that I previously created using `pipenv`.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Nice! I also found out in the meantime that there is a difference between 'create new project' and 'open'. The latter does check in a default location. I symlinked that to where my WORKON_HOME points, and that worked.

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf Not the case anymore, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306431/pycharm-warns-package-requirement-not-satisfied-when-using-pipenv-to-install-pac

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to update PyCharm. I updated to [2018.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=mac).

Export path for pipenv: `$ export PATH="$PATH:Users/{user_name}/.local/bin"`

PyCharm will then automatically detect **pipenv** under **new environment using** dropbox. [Reference image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBXiB.png) and see full blog post [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pipenv.html).