# Setting up the appropriate character encoding for a pipenv project in the pycharm console

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, pycharm, pipenv

I have setup a pipenv project in `/home/user/code/myproject/` using

```
pipenv --three
```

I have added `myproject` directory as project directory in `PyCharm` and have setup environment for `PyCharm` to use `pipenv` from

```
File > Default Settings > Project Interpreter >
```

[image]

But when I run any command from within the console of `PyCharm` like

```
pipenv install <package-name>
```

It gives error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 676, in main
    _verify_python3_env()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/_unicodefun.py", line 118, in _verify_python3_env
    'for mitigation steps.' + extra)
RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment.  Consult http://click.pocoo.org/python3/for mitigation steps.

This system lists a couple of UTF-8 supporting locales that
you can pick from.  The following suitable locales where
discovered: af_ZA.UTF-8, am_ET.UTF-8, be_BY.UTF-8, bg_BG.UTF-8, ca_ES.UTF-8, cs_CZ.UTF-8, da_DK.UTF-8, de_AT.UTF-8, de_CH.UTF-8, de_DE.UTF-8, el_GR.UTF-8, en_AU.UTF-8, en_CA.UTF-8, en_GB.UTF-8, en_IE.UTF-8, en_NZ.UTF-8, en_US.UTF-8, es_ES.UTF-8, et_EE.UTF-8, eu_ES.UTF-8, fi_FI.UTF-8, fr_BE.UTF-8, fr_CA.UTF-8, fr_CH.UTF-8, fr_FR.UTF-8, he_IL.UTF-8, hr_HR.UTF-8, hu_HU.UTF-8, hy_AM.UTF-8, is_IS.UTF-8, it_CH.UTF-8, it_IT.UTF-8, ja_JP.UTF-8, kk_KZ.UTF-8, ko_KR.UTF-8, lt_LT.UTF-8, nl_BE.UTF-8, nl_NL.UTF-8, no_NO.UTF-8, pl_PL.UTF-8, pt_BR.UTF-8, pt_PT.UTF-8, ro_RO.UTF-8, ru_RU.UTF-8, sk_SK.UTF-8, sl_SI.UTF-8, sr_YU.UTF-8, sv_SE.UTF-8, tr_TR.UTF-8, uk_UA.UTF-8, zh_CN.UTF-8, zh_HK.UTF-8, zh_TW.UTF-8
```

How to setup the encoding in `PyCharm`? Same is working fine from terminal directly.

> Edit 2

The `Setting > Editor > File Encoding` window shows global encoding set to `UTF-8`.
[image]

Output of `$ locale` in terminal

```
$ locale                                                                                                                                                                           
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

and output of `$ locale` in `PyCharm` console

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

**How to set appropriate encoding type? i.e., `en_US.UTF-8`? I'm using Macbook Air (Sierra)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly setup pipenv in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251411/how-do-i-properly-setup-pipenv-in-pycharm)

Comment: FYI for those wondering "why python3 can error out because of something small like unset locale (i.e. env vars `LANG`, `LC_ALL`)" --> read [PEP 538](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0538/) and the related [PEP 540](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0540/). The error appears to only be an issue for python 3.0 to 3.6 because PEP 538 fixes the issues for python >= 3.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encoding issue with python3 and click package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234393/encoding-issue-with-python3-and-click-package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if just change the encoding of Pycharm,you can click: 
setting->Editor->File Encodings.
It is suggested that you change all the language option to UTF-8.

You are dealing with an environment where Python 3 thinks you are restricted to ASCII data. The solution to these problems is different depending on which locale your computer is running in.

For instance, if you have a German Linux machine, you can fix the problem by exporting the locale to de_DE.utf-8:

export LC_ALL=de_DE.utf-8
export LANG=de_DE.utf-8

If you are on a US machine, en_US.utf-8 is the encoding of choice. On some newer Linux systems, you could also try C.UTF-8 as the locale:

export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
export LANG=C.UTF-8

**You need to do this before you invoke your Python script.**

You could search the usage of **locale** and **export**.
if you want to change the type of local setting,just use:
export =value.
LC_CTYPE is the most import var ,ohters are used to define the format of (money,message,date or time,etc)
you can only change this to en_US.UTF-8:

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

LC_ALL is a global var,it will overwrite all the LC_*(not Lang)

Comment: I'm using US Machine (Macbook Air) in India

Comment: just type this in pycharm  Terminal(console):            export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"