# Pycharm warns package requirement not satisfied when using pipenv to install package

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm, pipenv

I am trying to install packages into my Pycharm environment using pipenv. However, when I use `pipenv install <package name>`, a popup appears on the top mentioning

> "Package requirement not satisfied"

and asks me to "install requirements from Pipfile.lock"

When I started the project, I selected Pipenv as my project interpreter.Why is PyCharm asking to re-install a package from the Pipfile.lock file when I clearly used pipenv from the beginning and set the project to use Pipenv as an interpreter. Am I double installing ?

[image]

[image]

**Update**:

It is now reported as a bug in PyCharm, please vote for the issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34622

Comment: Have you looked at the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251411/how-do-i-properly-setup-pipenv-in-pycharm)? Also are you sure the pipenv environment you're installing into in the terminal is the same one you set for the project interpreter? It seems like maybe when you install via the terminal, it installs to a different virtualenv, updates the Pipfile.lock, and then PyCharm detects a new dependency in that file that doesn't exist in the pipenv it's using.

Comment: Take a look at [this JetBrains support thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001522219-Package-requirements-not-satisfied-though-they-are-) and see if that resolves the issue you're having.

Comment: That's an unfortunate PyCharm bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34622 Please vote for the ticket.

Comment: Voted. Thanks for the heads up and workaround.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is in [this answer on the JetBrains support forums](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001522219/comments/360000242119).

The steps are as follows:

1. Go to **File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...** and press **Invalidate and Restart**.
2. Once restarted, add the interpreter back, wait for the stubs to be rebuilt and then check to if the problem has been resolved.
3. If not, then first remove the pipenv interpreter as the project interpreter by going to **File > Settings > Project:  > Project Interpreter** and setting the project interpreter to **No Interpreter**. Click Apply and OK. Then repeat steps 1 and 2 and see if it solves the problem.

I'm not sure why this problem occurs, but it seems to solve it when it comes up.

**EDIT 07/29/19:**

[This bug has been fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34622) in the [2019.2 Release of PyCharm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/PyCharm+2019.2+Release+Notes).

Comment: @Matthew Okay, I've incorporated your feedback into my answer to save people some extra work if it's not required. Thanks =)

Comment: I still think this is really strange, that although you start a new project with pipenv, and install within the terminal of pipenv, PyCharm fails to find the interpreter. I will send this question to PyCharm :D It just does not make sense to me.

Comment: Did you ever try removing pipenv from the project interpreter first like that post suggested? Not sure if it makes a difference or not. I've had that same warning pop up for me, but it did eventually go away and I'm not sure what I did to fix it.

Comment: Oh I see, that's unfortunate. I hope they respond with a better solution, which you can post here as an answer and accept if it solved it for you. I'll leave my solution up for context.

Comment: @MIhau It is now reported as a major bug in PyCharm https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34622 Please vote for the issue

Comment: Still encountered the same issue (or very similar) in PyCharm 2020.2.3 on Ubuntu 20.04. `Invalidate Caches/Restart` does indeed seem to help.

Comment: Still getting this issue on 2020.3 with invalidating caches/restarting making no difference.

Answer (score 2):

I had an old `requirements.txt` laying around after switching to `setup.py` and `pip install -e .`.

Removed the `requirements.txt` and the warnings disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your paths are right.

for me, I was using venv, so its path should be the same path of the project + "/.venv"

that solved the problem for me.

[image]

and the same for pipenv:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm still running into this issue on 2020.3. I think it's because when setting up the interpreter the python interpreter is in a virtualenv and the pipenv install is in $PYENV_ROOT/versions. To workaround this, I just set the interpreter as a virtualenv environment and manage pipenv through the CLI.